# Humidity Sensor Bathroom Fan (UK)

Tags: bathtub

Wonder if anyone can help?

I have just replaced an old timed electic fan with a new humidity / timed sensor fan.

The fan location has a  1x Perminant Live,  1x swiched Live (bathroom Light) and 1x Netraul.

Which is fine, however I dont want to use the switched live as I dont need the fan running when the light is turned on.

So my simple mind was thinking if I just exlude the switched live, the fan will not come on when the light is turned on.

However with the perminant live thats supplied via an isolation switch connected to the perminant feed on the fan the fan just contiuously runs (been on about 45 minutes since install and still running)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the fan manufacturer/model number? Have you looked through the manual?

Comment: It's not generally recommend to only use a humidistat by itself

Answer (score 2):

Ok Guys

Realized the error of my ways

I had the humidity setting on 40%, once changed to a starting point of 90% (as read on another forum) the fan switched of after a short time.

Put a bit of steam in front of it and it tunred back on, which is how I wanted it, so all good now.

Comment: Nicely done. FYI: an automatic switch that is controlled by moisture levels is a ' humidistat'.